# Date on x-axis is being ordered randomly even the chronological order is correct in the data set I am using

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data set.

[image: Data-set I have]

The 'Date' column (from 11/29/2017 to 1/16/2018) is in the correct order in my dataset. However, when I do a barplot using ggplot2, the dates on the x-axis are being reordered randomly. I have tried reorder() method and it doesn't work. I have attached the code and data I have right now. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

```
nest_men_women <- melt(mydata[, c('Date', 'Women', 'Men')], id.vars = 1)
view(nest_men_women)

ggplot(nest_men_women, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable, position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
               stat = "identity", width = 0.8)) +

  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Women"="lightpink", "Men" = "steelblue3"))+

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(20,40,60,80,100))+

  theme_light()+

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), 
        legend.background = element_blank(), legend.justification = c(1,1),
        axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(colour = "lightgrey", color = "lightgrey", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.line.y.left = element_line(colour = "lightgrey", color = "lightgrey", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.line.x.top = element_line(colour = "lightgrey", color = "lightgrey", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(colour = "lightgrey", color = "lightgrey", linetype = "solid"))+

  geom_text(data = nest_men_women, 
            aes(Date, label = value), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), colour="black", 
            check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = -1, hjust = 1, size = 3.8, 
            inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

[image: Here is the plot I am getting as an output]

Comment: What is the type of `Date`column?

Comment: Your image is too small to read but I am guessing that the Date column values have been read as factors, instead of dates. See what `str(nest_men_women)` returns. And please include data as plain text using _e.g._ `dput()`, not images, so we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Add `nest_men_women$Date <- as.Date(nest_men_women$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")` to convert your `Date` column into the date data type. It's currently factor or character as is being displayed in alphabetical order.

Comment: @fmarm The type is being shown as a factor.

Comment: then converting the Date column to datatype Date should help.

Comment: @JonSpring This is converting the `Date` column values to `N/A`

Comment: Perhaps `nest_men_women$Date <- as.Date(as.character(nest_men_women$Date), format = "%m/%d/%y")`?

Comment: @neilfws I tried `dput()`. When I am trying to paste the output here it says too long!

Comment: @JonSpring This worked:   `nest_men_women$Date <- as.character(as.Date.factor((nest_men_women$Date), format = "%m/%d/%y"))`. It changed the format to 'YYYY-MM-DD' , but that works as long as it is ordered! Thank you so much!! Can you also please suggest how else I can re-position the labels in my plot (attached in the question)... I played with `nudge_y/nudge_x` along with `hjust/vjust` and `position_dodge()`. Nothing aligns it perfectly!